# How to configuring RPi to connect to only one device at a time using Python BlueZ

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

I am using [this guide](https://scribles.net/creating-ble-gatt-server-uart-service-on-raspberry-pi/) to setup a BLE-based UART communication and using Nordic's nRF Toolbox to connect with the Raspberry Pi 4.

Everything works as expected only issue I am facing is that the RPi will connect to multiple devices as the BLE advertising doesn't stop once connected to first device.

In ideal case I want the RPi to connect to only one device at a time.

I am able to start and stop the discoverability of the RPi via the terminal menu after using `bluetoothctl` command. But I am not sure how to do the same using Python code. I would also appreciate if you can point me towards BlueZ Python documentation. Please bear with me as I mostly do embedded C programming.

Comment: Google `BlueZ Python documentation` for the PyBlueZ documentation. As far as the rest of the question is concerned, it's extremely broad and unfocused. Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What version of BluZz are you using? Your desired behaviour was the default behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56662406/7721752.  The BlueZ API uses D-Bus which is usable in any language that has D-Bus bindings. The BlueZ API documentation is at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc